# KotlinNullPointerException when trying to fetch data using retrofit and display using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

I am trying to display list of repositories from github using the retrofit library and then display it using the recyclerView library. I have checked before adding recyclerView that data is fetched successfully. But after adding recyclerView, I am getting NullPointerException.

Below is code for my Viewmodel, fragment, adapter and data class

ListViewModel.kt

```
package com.kunalrai.githubtrends

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class ListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var repoList: MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>

    fun getRepos(): MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>{

            repoList = MutableLiveData()
            loadRepos()

        return repoList
    }

    private fun loadRepos() {
        Api.RETROFIT_SERVICE.getRepos().enqueue( object: Callback<List<Repo>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Repo>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("Failure: ", t.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Repo>>, response: Response<List<Repo>>) {
                if(response.body() != null){
                    repoList.value = response.body()!!
                    Log.i("response.body :",""+response.body()!!)
                }

            }
        })
    }

}
```

ListFragment.kt

```
package com.kunalrai.githubtrends

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.kunalrai.githubtrends.databinding.ListFragmentBinding


class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ListFragment()
    }

    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ListFragmentBinding
    var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter
    var repoList: List<Repo>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = ListFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner

        binding.viewmodel = viewModel
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.rv_repo_list)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)

        viewModel.getRepos().observe(this,
            Observer<List<Repo>> { repoList ->
                recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList!!)
                recyclerView!!.adapter = recyclerAdapter
            })


        return binding.root
    }

}
```

ListAdapter.kt

```
package com.kunalrai.githubtrends

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions

class ListAdapter(private val context: Context?, private val repoList: List<Repo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.repo_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return repoList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.author.text = repoList[position].author

        holder.repo.text = repoList[position].name

        Glide.with(context!!).load(repoList[position].avatar)
            .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
            .into(holder.image)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        val author: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.owner_name)
        val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.owner_image)
        val repo: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.repo_name)


    }
}
```

Repo.kt (data class)

```
package com.kunalrai.githubtrends

import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class Repo(
    @Json(name = "author")
    var author: String,
    @Json(name = "name")
    var name: String,
    @Json(name = "description")
    var desc: String,
    @Json(name = "avatar")
    var avatar: String,
    @Json(name = "language")
    var language: String,
    @Json(name = "url")
    var url: String,
    @Json(name = "stars")
    var stars: String,
    @Json(name = "forks")
    var forks: String
)
```

My error stack :- 
(updated)

```
2019-11-29 16:43:57.686 20703-20703/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-11-29 16:43:57.688 20703-20703/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-11-29 16:44:03.865 20703-20703/com.kunalrai.githubtrends E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: Is this line 47 of ListFragment?

`recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList!!)`

Comment: instead of using `repoList!!` in `recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList!!)` you should use repoList ?: emptyList() like `recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList ?: emptyList())`

Comment: Sounds like adding the exception stack trace to know where you got the KotlinNPE would have been helpful.

Comment: No NPE anymore. I have edited the stack trace. Can't display the data still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when using `!!` in Kotlin because it can cause `NullPointerException`. Replace it by `variable?.let{}` and `variable?.`

For this block of code:

```
viewModel.getRepos().observe(this,
        Observer<List<Repo>> { repoList ->
            recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList!!)
            recyclerView!!.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        })
```

You can change to:

```
class ListFragment {
    //Define adapter as global variable
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateView(...) {
        ...

        //Init adapter only once
        recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, repoList)
        //Use binding to make sure the view exist. You can remove findViewById command
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter

        viewModel.getRepos().observe(this,
            Observer<List<Repo>> { 
                it?.let { repoList ->
                    recyclerAdapter?.swapData(repoList)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

`variableName?.let{}` only execute commands inside `{}` block when the variableName is not null

Edit your adapter:

```
class ListAdapter() {
    private val repoList: ArrayList<Repo> = ArrayList()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(repoList[position])
    }

    fun swapData(repoList: List<Repo>) {
        this.repoList.clear()
        this.repoList.addAll(repoList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {
        fun bindView(repo: Repo) {
            //Do you binding here, you can get context from itemView.context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. No crashes. But still can't print data in recyclerView. Can you detect what's wrong? I am adding data class as well.

Comment: Can you try to debug and check if the line `recyclerView?.adapter = recyclerAdapter` called?

Comment: I am unable to use clear and addAll methods on my list. Both are unresolved.

Comment: Sorry, `repoList` in the `Adapter` should be `ArrayList` instead of `List`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.rv_repo_list)
```

with

```
    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_repo_list)
    val adapter =  ListAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

So you can avoid use all null-safe code, because it is instantiate both layout and adapter